# I need to remove woocommerce_recently_viewed cookie request by WooCommerce

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I tried to remove woocommerce_recently_viewed and wp_woocommerce_session_ from request because they caused the cache to bypass. How can I get rid of them?

--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: wp_woocommerce_session_0bd62b3da8371942755689bec5212ebc=t_820be1e25641a0b4b8180b37fed3d4%7C%7C1683702582%7C%7C1683698982%7C%7Cba06a09563edefc27c4c5c9d21eba4b5; expires=Wed, 10-May-2023 07:09:42 GMT; Max-Age=172800; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: woocommerce_recently_viewed=1681454; path=/
--  TTL            VCL 86400 0 0 1683529783 uncacheable

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

# Add hostnames, IP addresses and subnets that are allowed to purge content
acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
    "::1";
}

sub vcl_recv {   
    # Remove empty query string parameters
    # e.g.: www.example.com/index.html?
    if (req.url ~ "\?$") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }

    # Remove port number from host header
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    # Sorts query string parameters alphabetically for cache normalization purposes
    set req.url = std.querysort(req.url);

    # Remove the proxy header to mitigate the httpoxy vulnerability
    # See https://httpoxy.org/
    unset req.http.proxy;
    
    # Add X-Forwarded-Proto header when using https
    if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        if(std.port(server.ip) == 443 || std.port(server.ip) == 8443) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
        }
    }

    # Purge logic to remove objects from the cache. 
    # Tailored to the Proxy Cache Purge WordPress plugin
    # See https://wordpress.org/plugins/varnish-http-purge/
    if(req.method == "PURGE") {
        if(!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405,"PURGE not allowed for this IP address"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Purge-Method == "regex") {
            ban("obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.url + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
            return(synth(200, "Purged"));
        }
        ban("obj.http.x-url == " + req.url + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
        return(synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    # Only handle relevant HTTP request methods
    if (
        req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "PATCH" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE"
    ) {
        return (pipe);
    }

    # Remove tracking query string parameters used by analytics tools
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "");
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?&", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }

    #Google Adwords
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"    
    if (req.url ~ "\#") {
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\#.*$", "");
    }

    # Remove the "has_js" cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove a ";" prefix in the cookie if present
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

        # remove recent 
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "woocommerce_recently_viewed=*", "; recentviewdjunk=");

        # Remove test cookie
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=", "; wpjunk=");

    # Send Surrogate-Capability headers to announce ESI support to backend
    set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "key=ESI/1.0";
    # Only cache GET and HEAD requests
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        set req.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:REQUEST-METHOD";
        return(pass);
    }

    # Mark static files with the X-Static-File header, and remove any cookies
    # X-Static-File is also used in vcl_backend_response to identify static files
    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|ogg|ogm|opus|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip|html)(\?.*)?$") {
        set req.http.X-Static-File = "true";
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    unset req.http.set-cookie;
        return(hash);
    }


    # do not cache backend for xml-rpc
    if (req.url ~ "xmlrpc.php"){
      return (pass);
    }
    # No caching of special URLs, logged in users and some plugins
    if (
        req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_(?!test_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|wp-postpass|comment_author_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+|woocommerce_cart_hash|woocommerce_items_in_cart|wp_woocommerce_session_[a-zA-Z0-9]+|wordpress_logged_in_|comment_author" ||
        req.http.Authorization ||
        req.url ~ "add_to_cart" ||
        req.url ~ "nowprocket" ||
        req.url ~ "edd_action" ||
        req.url ~ "nocache" ||
        req.url ~ "^/addons" ||
        req.url ~ "^/bb-admin" ||
        req.url ~ "^/bb-login.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/bb-reset-password.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/cart" ||
        req.url ~ "^/checkout" ||
        req.url ~ "^/control.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/login" ||
        req.url ~ "^/logout" ||
        req.url ~ "^/lost-password" ||
        req.url ~ "^/my-account" ||
        req.url ~ "^/product" ||
        req.url ~ "^/register" ||
        req.url ~ "^/register.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/server-status" ||
        req.url ~ "^/signin" ||
        req.url ~ "^/signup" ||
        req.url ~ "^/stats" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wc-api" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-admin" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wcpa_uploads" ||
    req.url ~ "^/uploads" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-comments-post.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-cron.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-login.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-activate.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-mail.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^/wp-login.php" ||
        req.url ~ "^\?add-to-cart=" ||
        req.url ~ "^\?wc-api=" ||
        req.url ~ "^/preview=" ||
        req.url ~ "^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/"
    #req.url ~ "nowprocket"
    ) {
         set req.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Logged in/Got Sessions";
         if(req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
             set req.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Ajax";
         }
        return(pass);
    }

#set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "woocommerce_recently_viewed=[^;]+(; )?", "");
# remove Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
#    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
#        unset req.http.cookie;
#   return(hash);
#    }
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }
return (hash);
#return(hash);
  # remove recent view
#set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "woocommerce_recently_viewed", "");

    # Remove any cookies left

#    unset req.http.Cookie;
#    return(hash);
#    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
#        unset req.http.cookie;
#         return(hash);
#    }
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        # Create cache variations depending on the request protocol       
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Inject URL & Host header into the object for asynchronous banning purposes
    set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = bereq.http.host;


#if ( beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "image" )
#   {
#       set beresp.ttl = 2h; ## 1 hour TTL for images
#   }
    # If we dont get a Cache-Control header from the backend
    # we default to 1h cache for all objects
    if (!beresp.http.Cache-Control) {
        set beresp.ttl = 24h;
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES:Forced";
    }

    # If the file is marked as static we cache it for 1 day
    if (bereq.http.X-Static-File == "true") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES:Forced";
        set beresp.ttl = 1d;
    }

    # Remove the Set-Cookie header when a specific Wordfence cookie is set
    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie ~ "woocommerce_recently_viewed") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
     }
    
    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Cookies";
    } elseif(beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private";
    }   
  # Cache all static files by Removing all cookies for static files - Note: These file extensions are generated by WordPress WP Super Cache.
  if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(html|htm|gz)(\?.*)?$") {
    set beresp.ttl = 1d; # set a TTL for these optional.
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
  }
return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Debug header
    if(req.http.X-Cacheable) {
        set resp.http.X-Cacheable = req.http.X-Cacheable;    
    } elseif(obj.uncacheable) {
        if(!resp.http.X-Cacheable) {
            set resp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:UNCACHEABLE";        
        }
    } elseif(!resp.http.X-Cacheable) {
        set resp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
    }
    
if (obj.hits > 0) { ## Add the X-Cache: HIT/MISS/BYPASS header
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT"; ## If we had a HIT
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS"; ## If we had a MISS
    }
    # Cleanup of headers
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;    
}
```

I set these but no lucks. Cookies are still presented.

```
sub vcl_recv
        # remove recent 
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "woocommerce_recently_viewed=*", "; recentviewdjunk=");




sub vcl_backend_response {

    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie ~ "woocommerce_recently_viewed) {
            unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
         }



        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
                unset req.http.cookie;
        }
return (hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to just strip off the entire `SetCookie` response header if it contains `woocommerce_recently_viewed`.

If other cookies are also being set through this header, some unwanted side-effects might take place.

I would recommend that you look at your WooCommerce setup and figure out why it is setting these cookies. Maybe there's some behavior you can change in your WooCommerce configuration or code.

If you decide you really need to strip off `woocommerce_recently_viewed` & `wp_woocommerce_session_*` from the `Set-Cookie` header, I recommend that you find the right regular expression that matches all the cookie attributes. Cookies in the `Set-Cookie` header are different than the ones in the subsequent `Cookie` request headers.

When it comes to stripping off cookies in general, have a look at the following tutorial: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/removing-cookies-varnish/.

There's a specific section in the tutorial about a Varnish module to make the removal of cookies (both `Cookie` & `Set-Cookie`) a lot easier. See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/removing-cookies-varnish/#removing-cookies-with-vmod_cookie